# Does ExtJS binding ignore commented out code?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

If I have a formula in my binding that uses a 'get' on something that does not exist, then my function 'myFunction' does not compute. No error is thrown (which is a shame), but at least nothing is shown on my component where I am binding this formula to.

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',


    formulas: {

        myFunction: function(get) {

            var fdn = get('fullDisplayName') ? get('fullDisplayName'): "";

            var code = get('this.is.something.that.does.not.exist') ? get('this.is.something.that.does.not.exist'): "";

            return fdn + code;
        },

        fullDisplayName: function(get) {
            var title = get('ref_mainApplicantTitle.selection.text') ? get('ref_mainApplicantTitle.selection.text') : "";
            var fName = get('tsk_forCase_mainApplicant_fname0') ? get('tsk_forCase_mainApplicant_fname0') : "";
            var lName = get('tsk_forCase_mainApplicant_lname0') ? get('tsk_forCase_mainApplicant_lname0') : "";

            return ("" + title + " " + fName + " " + lName + "").trim();
        },
```

What is really bizarre is that, if I comment out the 'get' line to a non-existant binding, it STILL does not work

```
myFunction: function(get) {

    var fdn = get('fullDisplayName') ? get('fullDisplayName'): "";

    //var code = get('this.is.something.that.does.not.exist') ? get('this.is.something.that.does.not.exist'): "";

    return fdn + code;
},
```

If I change the code in the commented out code to a binding that DOES exist, then everything works OK!

```
myFunction: function(get) {

    var fdn = get('fullDisplayName') ? get('fullDisplayName'): "";

    //var code = get('fullDisplayName') ? get('fullDisplayName'): "";

    return fdn + code;
},
```

Why would ExtJS ignore my commented out code?

I am thinking of submitting this as a bug to Sencha, but thought I would just throw it out there on SO incase I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Well, when you comment out the non-existent binding, I would still expect it not to work because ``code`` is now undefined....

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the code of [`parseFormula`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/src/Formula.js.html#Ext.app.bind.Formula) for understanding the behavior (it parses the string of the formula).

I suggest you define the bindings explicitly like:

```
myFunction: {
  bind: {
    fullDisplayName: '{fullDisplayName}',
    //foo: '{this.is.something.that.does.not.exist}'
  },
  get: function(data) {

    var fdn = data.fullDisplayName ? data.fullDisplayName : "";

     //var code = data.foo ? data.foo : "";

    return fdn + code;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, Sencha forgot to account for comments in their function content string parsing function.

Comment: By the way, that makes me wonder what happens when you put their function content string parsing function into their function content string parsing function.